# Make the Android app as a Server..?

Tags: php, android, soap, nusoap

How to make the android app as Server. I installed web server in the Android device and tried to call the service from the php which is the client. Its telling that it is unable to listen to the socket. I Implemented SOAP to send the request from the Php client to the Android server. Any suggestion.>? 
Or is there any other method.? other than TCP socket listening.

Answer (score 0):

please read below link fetch data from server to andriod mobile

```
  http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html
```